# How to use ST_Collect to find all polygons with matching ID?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I have a PostGIS table which holds many polygons. Some polygons have the same ID but are their own discrete area.

How do I do an update query on table which takes groups of polygons with matching ID's and combines them into a single multipolygon geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ST_Collect on the geometry column then group by ID. You can refine the query with a where clause etc if needed but as long you group by ID you will get what you are after.

```
SELECT id, ST_Collect(geom)
FROM table
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Will the GROUP BY clause work as part of an UPDATE query?
I tried explain on: UPDATE table SET geom = ST_Collect(geom) GROUP BY id; and it failed.

Comment: I cheated. I used your query and just did SELECT INTO a new table to get the desired result. Thanks.

Comment: Yes of course. In some way you have to define how to handle the reduced number of rows. Creating a new table is the cleanest.

Comment: I agree with Nicklas; if you have 4 record with the same ID you will get 4 records with identical geometries using this query